# Lync presence in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, lync-2013

What plugin I need install and where can I download it for Chrome to get the lync presence indicator to work correctly. Version of Chrome is 46.0.2490.42 beta-m (64-bit). In Internet Explorer and Firefox everything works fine.

Comment: Where I can download sharepoint browser plug-in for google chrome?

Comment: Lync presence will not work for chrome browser.